# FaultException and no WCF service

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, soap, xml-serialization, faultexception

I'm receiving the following `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` in my Windows Phone app. A bit of research on this exception shows that it is related to a SOAP fault. That's odd since I am not making any soap calls, especially when the exception comes up.

It seems to come up after I navigate between pages and gets progressively worse as I try to use the app.

I have two Webclient calls, but most of the time those are avoided by local caching of the data (so I am able to comment them out and still use my app), yet I still receive these errors.

I can't seem to find any useful source online so hopefully someone knows about this and how to get around it. Even if I am able to swallow the exception, that would be somewhat helpful for today.

Now that I'm typing this, I'm wondering if it has to do with the xmlnamespace in the xml data I'm caching in isolated storage. Anybody heard of this happening?

Update:
well, when I don't load the xml and deserialize it, I don't get the FaultExceptions. Perhaps if I can get rid of the namespace...

Comment: This is a problem reading from isolated storage. My partner figured it out, I'll try to find the post on it to reference it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by having the Isolated Storage Explorer attached. Removing this reference fixed it.